# Creating a diverse people group in Python?

Tags: python, group-by, grouping

I am trying to create a diverse group of people from a database. For example I have following data

```
1. Male, PhD, Computer Science, German, age: 34, no experience
2. Male, Masters, Biology, Austrian, age: 39, no experience
3. Female, Masters, Biology, Swiss, age: 20,  experienced
4. Male, PhD, Biology, German, age: 28,  experienced
5. Female, PhD, Computer Science, American, age: 29, no experience
6. Male, Masters, Biology, Canadian, age: 21, no experience
7. Male, Bachelors, Computer Science, Asian, age: 20, experienced
8. Female, Bachelors, Computer Science, Indian, age: 20, no experience
```

I want to create groups of 4 students with most diverse characteristics plus a condition that two bachelors cannot be in the same group. 
Diversity means; we want to have a balance of PhD and Master students in both groups, we want to have male female ratio in the group almost similar, however, for age we want to keep the OLD ones TOGETHER and younger ones TOGETHER.
Obviously it cannot be that we can find totally diverse group, but we should be able to follow the diversity as much as possible...

Comment: Is your dataset loaded as a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Is there a particular question about the code you've already written that we could help you with?  Right now it's not so much a question you have as an oddly specific task you want us to complete.

Comment: No I m not working with pandas
I actually tried coding a bit. I am able to put conditions like  W1_condition = (W1[Id1] == W1[Id2]) and  W2_condition = (W2[Id1] != W2[Id2]). The problem I m having is; how to keep a balance of these variables in the groups. The above conditions (with several others) only specifically give me those students that match, but I am not able to form group based on the  limitations on the selections. I hope I can get some direction o proceed further